# при скролле заголовки двигались вместе с контентом Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Format (php)

Tags: php, html, jquery, excel, phpexcel

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможность средствами Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Format (php) в xls документе сделать первую строку прайса статичной. Строка содержит основные заголовки а-ля: название продукта, его цена и так далее. Клиент хочет, чтобы при просмотре документа содержимое прайса скроллилось, в то время как шапка оставалась на месте. Можно ли это запрограммить или это из области фантастики ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, поможет ли в конечном результате, но подтолкнуть должно:

```
var header = $('.header'),
  headertop = header.offset().top,
  $window = $(window),
  parentwidth = header.parent().outerWidth()

$window.scroll(function() {
  if ($window.scrollTop() >= headertop) {
    $(header).addClass('sticked').css('width', parentwidth)
  }
  else if ($window.scrollTop() >= $(header).parent().outerHeight()) {
    $(header).removeClass('sticked')
  } else {
    $(header).removeClass('sticked')
  }
});
```

```js
var header = $('.header'),
  headertop = header.offset().top,
  $window = $(window),
  parentwidth = header.parent().outerWidth()

$window.scroll(function() {
  if ($window.scrollTop() >= headertop) {
    $(header).addClass('sticked').css('width', parentwidth)
  }
  else if ($window.scrollTop() >= $(header).parent().outerHeight()) {
    $(header).removeClass('sticked')
  } else {
    $(header).removeClass('sticked')
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #c0c0c0;
  }
.wrapper {
  background: #fff;
  height: 300%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
.table {
    width: 100%;
}


ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100%;
  }

li {
  flex: 25%;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding:10px;
  
}
.sticked {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="table">
 <ul class="header">
  <li>Заголовок 1
    <li>Заголовок 2
      <li>Заголовок 3
       <li>Заголовок 4
  </ul>
   <ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>21</li>
  <li>22</li>
  <li>23</li>
  <li>24</li>
</ul>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: это же в xls документе
js не катит